# Is there a striaght forward way to show a readable overview of how the dependency structure between two versions of an R package differs?

Tags: r, dependencies

Assume I want to compare the dependencies of e.g. `devtools 2.4.2` with `devtools 2.4.5`. Is there some prebuilt function "somewhere" that will return a readable output informing me on what has changed in the dependency structure (including minimum required versions) of the package?

Currently, the only option I see is manually comparing the `DESCRIPTION` files and taking notes. I'm aware - of course - that I can probably write something myself but the question is more or less whether someone has already done this and where I can find that.

Comment: Maybe check out https://github.com/r-lib/itdepends. It was discussed in this talk: https://www.jimhester.com/talk/2019-rsc-deps/. Not sure if it does exactly what you need but might be a start

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of goodies tucked away in base R package `tools`.  As you have both `DESCRIPTION` files (or can get them ...) you could use those.

Here is an example using CRAN package `rgl`:

```
> db <- tools:::.read_description("DESCRIPTION")
> tools:::.get_requires_from_package_db(db, "Suggests")
  Suggests1   Suggests2   Suggests3   Suggests4   Suggests5 
     "covr"      "curl"  "datasets"     "knitr" "rmarkdown" 
  Suggests6   Suggests7   Suggests8   Suggests9  Suggests10 
 "spelling"   "stringi"  "testthat"      "tzdb"     "waldo" 
 Suggests11  Suggests12 
    "withr"      "xml2" 
> tools:::.get_requires_from_package_db(db, "Imports")
   Imports1    Imports2    Imports3    Imports4    Imports5 
      "cli"     "clipr"    "crayon"       "hms" "lifecycle" 
   Imports6    Imports7    Imports8    Imports9   Imports10 
  "methods"        "R6"     "rlang"    "tibble"     "utils" 
  Imports11 
    "vroom" 
>
```

So you could collate those for `Imports`, `Depends`, `LinkingTo` and `Suggests` and then run a `setdiff()`.  After which you could pretty-print.

Comment: What about version numbers? I have updated the question text accordingly.

Comment: Sure, but that is now a different request.  "Usually" one cares about a) installability ("can the depends be satisfied") and b) cost ("how many are there?").   Doing all that versioned (PyPi or Conda style) is possible but not what base R does here.  But I pointed you to a soure you can build on to extend with the functionality you desire.